# jquery .each after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have several divs with class"revstory" and more are added with ajax.
prolem is, when ajax loads, the loaded divs aren't affected by the jquery script.

I've tried to add the script also in the ajax file.
the function works 2 times.

i've used ajaxComplete now it works many times!
i've been trying this for a while now . hope someone can guide me to the right solution.
Thanks in advance

```
<div id=#review class="revstory less">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function sf() {

    var less = '60px';
    var more = '300px';
    $('.revstory').each(function () {
        var rev = $(this);
        var h = this.scrollHeight;
        console.log(h);

        if (h > 70) {

            rev.css('height', less);
            rev.addClass("less");
            var l = rev.text();

            rev.text(l.substr(0, 155) + '..');

            // rev.after('<a id="more" class="item" href="#">Read more</a><br/>');
            // var link = rev.next();
        }


        rev.on('click', function () {

            if (rev.hasClass("less")) {
                rev.animate({
                    'height': h
                });
                rev.text(l.substr(0, 555));
                rev.removeClass("less");
            } else {
                rev.addClass("less");
                rev.animate({
                    'height': less
                });
                rev.text(l.substr(0, 155) + '..');
            }
            // rev.css('height', h);

            // alert(rev.attr('id'));
        });

    });
}
```

Comment: i can, but does nothing but post more divs which is working.

Comment: It's unusual to declare an event handler inside a function. Try moving `rev.on('click', function() {` out of your sf() function and replace it with `$(document).on('click', '.revstory', function() {`

Comment: It is difficult to diagnose your problem without knowing when and how `sf()` is called.

Comment: let me get this straight, you want the new elements also have the function of click?

Comment: yes, i want the new elemts to be loaded collapsed and when clicked they expand, just like the elemets before the ajax load

Comment: `<div id=#review ` should be `<div id="review" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unusual to declare an event handler inside a function. Try moving `rev.on('click'` out of your sf() function and replace it with `$(document).on('click', '.revstory'`

```
$(document).on('click', '.revstory', function() {
    var rev = $(this);                          // add this line, too
    if (rev.hasClass("less")) {
        rev.animate({
            'height': h
        });
        rev.text(l.substr(0, 555));
        rev.removeClass("less");
    } else {
        rev.addClass("less");
        rev.animate({
            'height': less
        });
        rev.text(rev.text().substr(0, 155) + '..'); // also update this
    }
    // rev.css('height', h);
    // alert(rev.attr('id'));
});

function sf() {    
    var less = '60px';
    var more = '300px';
    $('.revstory').each(function () {
        var rev = $(this);
        var h = this.scrollHeight;
        console.log(h);

        if (h > 70) {
            rev.css('height', less);
            rev.addClass("less");
            var l = rev.text();
            rev.text(l.substr(0, 155) + '..');
            // rev.after('<a id="more" class="item" href="#">Read more</a><br/>');
            // var link = rev.next();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: prolem is, .each gets all elements loaded but doesn't count the new ones after ajax load. so they're not affected by the script

Comment: Made one more revision. But as I said, you must provide us your AJAX call and/or whatever calls `sf()` in order to have the problem diagnosed.

Comment: Thanks, i took the on click event out of the function, now it works great!

Answer (score -1):

I think that you change this line:

```
rev.on('click',function(){
```

To:

```
rev.live('click',function(){
```

Maybe this can work

Comment: but you know which version he used?

Comment: You're making quite a leap of logic to assume that an old version of jQuery is his problem.